# Counting integers?

Tags: java, loops, integer

Hello I was doing my homework and when I got to this question I got confused. It is probably me just over thinking it but can anyone explain to me what it wants? I'm pretty sure it has a for or a while loop but I'm not sure.

Here is the question

Given three integers, a, b, and c, return a count of all the numbers in the range a to b, inclusive, that are multiples of c.

Ex)

countHowMany(1, 10, 2) → 5

countHowMany(2, 10, 3) → 3

countHowMany(3, 3, 3) → 1

Now what I was able to pull out of it was just the basics

```
Int countHowMany(int a, int b, int c) {
```

Can explain to me how to go from here?

Comment: Design an algorithm that solves the problem first. Then implement said algorithm in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will certainly have some type of decision loop.  Also think about the % [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14047358)

Comment: With respect, the op asked "how to go from there".  It seems to me that suggesting a decision loop and a modulus operator is a proper response to how to approach this solution.  

The op did not ask for code examples, nor would that have been ideal since this question was related to homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int countHowMany(int a, int b, int c) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if (i % c == 0) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: It should be i<=b, not i<b.  Inclusive.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking can you explain how it's a for loop? I'm just diving into Java with no experience so pardon if what I ask is dumb.

Comment: With that for loop, I create a variable called i with a value of a in the first part, then I tell Java to loop through the code as long as i is smaller  or equal than b in the second part and in the third part I tell it to increase i by 1 every time it loops. You can go read this link for more info http://www.java-examples.com/loop.

Comment: A `for` loop is a very naive approach - an O(n) solution. The teacher probably wants to see the O(1) solution.